# change label style temporary (imitate button)

Tags: python, qlabel, pyside2

I need to ask you guys for advice, as I'm running out of ideas. I'm working onclickable label. I have already done some "clickable label" class and handled mouseover event - which changes the label border and returns to the normal state when the mouse leaves.

Now I want it to have a custom glow effect on the label, but I want it to return to normal state after, let's say 0.5 s from a click.

I want my label with an image to imitate button. `time.sleep` does not work nice, especially with spamming clicks it freezes application main thread.

Hope I am not reinventing the wheel but as far as I know that's the way to go.

Heres the sample code, any answer is appreciated.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel, QSizePolicy, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide2.QtCore import (Signal, QEvent, QObject, QRect)


class ClickableLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, pic_path, width, height, border_color, click_function):
        super(ClickableLabel, self).__init__()

        # Setting the picture path and setting pixmap to label
        self.pic_path = pic_path
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.pic_path)
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        # Set the size
        self.setFixedSize(width, height)

        # Enable tracking and assign function
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.click_function = click_function

        # Set default 
        if border_color is None:
            self.border_color = 'lightblue'
        else:
            self.border_color = border_color

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid " + str(self.border_color) + ";")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        # event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        self.setStyleSheet("border: None")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.click_function()

        effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        effect.setOffset(0, 0)
        effect.setBlurRadius(20)
        effect.setColor(self.border_color)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a task after a while you should not use `time.sleep()` because as it blocks the GUI causing it not to behave correctly, the best option is to use `QTimer::singleShot()`.

On the other hand I see that you are passing a function so that it executes a task when it is clicked, that is not scalable, in Qt the correct thing is to create a signal and the advantage is that you can connect the same signal to several functions without coupling , that is, the one that emits the signal must not know in advance who will receive the signal.

I recommend taking values for defects for the arguments, I have taken the time to give an improvement to your code:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClickableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, pic_path="", width=80, height=30, border_color=QtGui.QColor("lightblue"), parent=None):
        super(ClickableLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic_path))
        self.setFixedSize(width, height)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.border_color = QtGui.QColor(border_color)
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self,
            offset=QtCore.QPointF(0, 0),
            blurRadius=20,
            color=self.border_color)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
        self.disable_effect()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid {};".format(self.border_color.name()))
        super(ClickableLabel, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("border: None")
        super(ClickableLabel, self).leaveEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        self.effect.setEnabled(True)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, self.disable_effect)
        super(ClickableLabel, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def disable_effect(self):
        self.effect.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    def on_click():
        print("click")

    w = ClickableLabel(pic_path="heart.png")
    w.clicked.connect(on_click)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Really thank you for your time @eyllanesc. Your improvement of code perfectly solves the problem. Really sad that my +1 is not visible due to my small reputation. Although hope it will be perfect example for others. Thank you for your other suggestion - I will keep that in mind learning PyQT (learned tkinter)

Comment: @Skulldron tkinter is a GUI of the old school, Qt allows you to create more scalable projects, so you understand the logic I recommend you read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Thank you, that's really usefull :).